# iOS Notification Center without Alert

Tags: ios, notifications, notificationcenter

Is there anyway to add notification to the Notification Center on iOS 5.x without actually sending a visual alert?

For example the built in Stock and Weather apps are persistently in the Notification Center and update the weather and stock prices don't don't send any other type of notifications. e.g. Banners, Badges, Alert.

I've searched the API documentation but it's rather lacking in information.

Comment: The weather and stock apps are widgets. For now, without jail breaking, there is no way to add custom widgets.

Comment: There seems to be other apps though like Date Notifier that app a notification (like Mail would) to the Notification Center without actually triggering an alert etc. At least they appear to,